# Laravel : Invalid datetime format: 1292 Incorrect datetime value: '2021-03-14 02:00:00'

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

i received a lots of **invalid datetime format** errors

```
[2021-03-14 02:00:00] production.ERROR: SQLSTATE[22007]: Invalid datetime format: 1292 Incorrect datetime value: '2021-03-14 02:00:00' for column `xxxxxxx`.`users`.`last_activity` at row 1 (SQL: update `users` set `last_activity` = 2021-03-14 02:00:00, `users`.`updated_at` = 2021-03-14 02:00:00 where `id` = 2561) {"userId":2561,"exception":"[object] (Illuminate\\Database\\QueryException(code: 22007): SQLSTATE[22007]:
[stacktrace]


[2021-03-14 02:58:46] production.ERROR: SQLSTATE[22007]: Invalid datetime format: 1292 Incorrect datetime value: '2021-03-14 02:58:46' for column `xxxx`.`posts`.`updated_at` at row 1 (SQL: update `posts` set `view` = `view` + 1, `posts`.`updated_at` = 2021-03-14 02:58:46 where `id` = 43018) {"exception":"[object] (Illuminate\\Database\\QueryException(code: 22007): SQLSTATE[22007]: Invalid datetime format: 1292 Incorrect datetime value: '2021-03-14 02:58:46' for column `xxxx`.`posts`.`updated_at` at row 1 (SQL: update `posts` set `view` = `view` + 1, `posts`.`updated_at` = 2021-03-14 02:58:46 where `id` = 43018) at /home/xxxx/xxxxx/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php:664, PDOException(code: 22007): SQLSTATE[22007]: Invalid datetime format: 1292 Incorrect datetime value: '2021-03-14 02:58:46' for column `xxxx`.`posts`.`updated_at` at row 1 at /home/xxxx/xxxx/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php:483)
[stacktrace]
```

**The errors started at**: 2021-03-14 02:00:00

**And ended at**: 2021-03-14 02:58:46

Everything worked fine for over a year

All is back to normal **without any code change**.

Can someone help me understand what's happening?

**config/app.php** :

1. 'timezone' => 'Africa/Tunis',

**Table structure** :

[image]
**Database server** :

- Server: Localhost via UNIX socket
- Server type: MariaDB
- Server connection: SSL is not being used Documentation
- Server version: 10.3.27-MariaDB-log-cll-lve - MariaDB Server
- Protocol version: 10
- User: xxx@localhost
- Server charset: cp1252 West European (latin1)

Comment: @Haytheme Dridi, what did you do to fix this error?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue is because of Daylight Saving Time (DST).

Your app is set to "Africa/Tunis", which I don't believe recognizes DST. But this is a database error, not an app error. Your database is apparently using a timezone that recognizes DST.

DST started on 2021-03-14 at 02:00:00. Because of this, times between 2021-03-14 02:00:00 and 2021-03-14 02:59:59 do not exist, and are not valid times, thus causing the errors you received.

Comment: So how i fix this? My app timezone is America/Los_Angeles as well as my server timezone. Server is centos 8. Do i have to change timezone anywhere else?

Comment: @AlauddinAhmed, you didn't specify which database you're using, but I'd suggest looking up the documentation on your database to learn how it determines the timezone to use.